# flash cs5.5, 2 motion tween for an object, 1 with ease and 1 without

Tags: flash, actionscript, physics

I have encountered an interesting situation, I would like to simulate a ball thrown by a goalkeeper from top. Ball is going to move from right to left, it is small at the beginning, getting bigger at the half, because it gains height, and small again at the end. The scenario is this. And I do not want to use any actionscript code because of the performance loss caused by the event listeners.

How can I simulate two different kinds of tween (horizontal move is without ease and vertical move is with easeOut and easeIn) in the design environment of Flash cs5.5

By the way, I have already tried using actionscript code however, because there so many concurrent event, a little lag is occured at the beginning of each tween start.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer by myself, I had always been using classic tween, so I did not have any information about motion tween, but when I googled, I see that motion tween is much more powerful. As a result, by using motion tween instead of classic tween, I am able to control the ease for different properties chosen from motion editor.